# Javascript only outputting default value in if else if

Tags: javascript

I am writing a quiz using html and javascript for a website.
My problem is, when I run my quiz to see my result, only the default value shows up. This happens no matter how I answer the quiz questions. Does anyone see what I can do to fix it? Each time a a question is answered, the totals for the different results are supposed to be updated (adding 1 if the question answer corresponds to the result & not adding 1 to the total for the result otherwise). I think there is something about my if statement that needs changing. I've played around with it, but cannot seem to figure out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Quiz</title>
        <style type = "text/css">
            em  { font-weight: bold;
                  color: black; }
            p   { font-size: 12pt; 
                  font-family: times new roman, sans-serif; color: black; }
            b   { font-size: 13pt; 
                  font-family: times new roman, sans-serif; color: black; }
        </style>
<script language="Javascript">

function process()
{
    var A = 0;
    var B = 0;
    var C = 0;
    var D = 0;

    var f = document.f;
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < f.q1.length; i++) if (f.q1[i].checked) value = f.q1[i].value;
        if (value == "1") { } /*corresponds to the answer being chosen, i.e. first answer*/
        if (value == "2") { C++; A++; B++; }
        if (value == "3") { C++; D++; A++; B++; }

    for (i = 0; i < f.q2.length; i++) if (f.q2[i].checked) value = f.q2[i].value;
        if (value == "1") { C++; D++; A++; }
        if (value == "2") { D++; A++; B++; }
        if (value == "3") { C++; A++; B++; }
        if (value == "4") { C++; D++; A++; B++; }

    for (i = 0; i < f.q3.length; i++) if (f.q3[i].checked) value = f.q3[i].value;
        if (value == "1") { D++; }
        if (value == "2") { }

    for (i = 0; i < f.q4.length; i++) if (f.q4[i].checked) value = f.q4[i].value;
        if (value == "1") { A++; }
        if (value == "2") { A++; B++; }
        if (value == "3") { C++; D++; A++; B++; }

    /*same format for all other questions*/

    var out = "A"; /*default value*/
    i = "A"; /*default value*/

    if (C > i) { out ="C"; i = "C"; } 
    if (B > i) { out ="B"; i = "B"; }
    if (D > i) { out ="D"; i = "D"; } 
    window.alert ("Based on your answers, your result is " + i + " !!"); } /*right now, i always outputs as A*/

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php include ('menu.html'); ?>
<? include ("file.php"); ?>
<br><p>Answer the questions below</p> <br>

<form name="f" method= "post" action= "file.php">

<p><b>1. Question1 Text?<br></b>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="ans" value="1">Q1 Ans1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="ans" value="2">Q1 Ans2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="ans" value="3">Q1 Ans3<br><br>

<b>2. Question2 Text?<br></b>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="ans" value="1">Q2 Ans1<br>        
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="ans" value="2">Q2 Ans2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="ans" value="3">Q2 Ans3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="ans" value="4">Q2 Ans4<br><br>

<b>3. Question3 Text?<br></b>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="ans" value="1">Q3 Ans1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="ans" value="2">Q3 Ans2<br><br>

<b>4. Question4 Text?<br></b>
    <input type="radio" name="q4" id="ans" value="1">Q4 Ans1<br>        
    <input type="radio" name="q4" id="ans" value="2">Q4 Ans2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="q4" id="ans" value="3">Q4 Ans3<br><br>


/*more questions with same format*/


<p>Thanks for taking the quiz.<p><br>
<input type="button" value="Result" onclick="process();"><br><br>
</form>

<div class="footer"><?php include('myfooter.html');?></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide an html/js fiddle.

Comment: I can provide the html, I have never used js fiddle. I have updated my code with the html

Comment: using a switch statement might help your code's readability.

Comment: `<!-- Commmenting in HTML -->`  `/* Commenting in JavaScript */`

Comment: Please fix your indentation to match the nesting level. It took me a few readings to realize that all the `if` statements were not in the bodies of the `for` loops..

Comment: Also, get in the habit of always putting braces around the `if` body, even if it's just one statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I'm seeing is that, in the sample for-loop below, the mistake is that only the first if statement will be included in the for-loop:

So, the code below is:

```
for (i = 0; i < f.q1.length; i++) if (f.q1[i].checked) value = f.q1[i].value;
    if (value == "1") { } /*corresponds to the answer being chosen, i.e. first answer*/
    if (value == "2") { C++; A++; B++; }
    if (value == "3") { C++; D++; F++; B++; }
```

actually doing this:

```
for (i = 0; i < f.q1.length; i++) {
    if (f.q1[i].checked) {
        value = f.q1[i].value;
    }
}

if (value == "1")  { } /*corresponds to the answer being chosen, i.e. first answer*/
if (value == "2") { 
    C++; A++; B++;
}
if (value == "3") { 
    C++; D++; F++; B++; 
}
```

Please adjust the code so that all the if statements are under the for-loop's scope:

```
for (i = 0; i < f.q1.length; i++) {
    if (f.q1[i].checked) {
        value = f.q1[i].value;
    }
    if (value == "1") { } /*corresponds to the answer being chosen, i.e. first answer*/
    if (value == "2") { C++; A++; B++; }
    if (value == "3") { C++; D++; F++; B++; }
}
```

In general, it's a bad practice to leave out { } even for a single statement for the reason above.

Plus, the code below:

```
var out = "A"; /*default value*/
i = "A"; /*default value*/
```

would end up in 'out' and 'i' variables receiving the string "A". You would want them to be:

```
var out = "A"; /*default value*/
i = A; /*default value*/
```

And also change the rest of the assignment statements below to rid of "" in order to have them receive the values rather than the string:

```
var out = "A"; 
i = A; 

if (C > i) { 
    out = "C"; i = C; 
}else if (B > i) { 
    out = "B"; i = B; 
}else if (D > i) { 
    out = "D"; i = D; 
} 
alert ("Based on your answers, your result is " + out + " !!");
```

One more thing, the first for loop includes a fauty statement "F++", which should be "A++" instead:

```
if (value == "3") { C++; D++; A++; B++; }
```

See the working code below:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnxsL/6/)

Comment: I formatted mine like this for all the questions & it has stopped running completely. Before, the default value would have been output, now nothing.

Comment: Insert console.log("here"); or alert("here"); line between the for-loops to ensure that the loops are executed correctly.

Comment: Also to note that the variable "value" has never been initialized, and even worse, it never gets re-initialized between the loops, thus the previous value gets carried over to the next loop.

Comment: Added JSFiddle in the answer above. I didn't change any logics in the for-loop.

Comment: I see your JSFiddle & it did run for me, thanks, but that is outputting numbers, not one of the choices for A, B, C or D.

Comment: Your code is not outputting due to the last error found. Change the last condition of the first for-loop as below: if (value == "3") { C++; D++; A++; B++; }, no F++

Comment: I also fixed that type in my code, but still nothing. Thanks for trying to help me with this. I see the same problem happening in your JSFiddle though. The default is A and no matter what answers I choose (I played around with your JSFiddle), the result is always A even there.

Comment: It might be the logic issue. It's hard for anyone outside to understand what the logic is trying to do. You might want to step through the logic to ensure that the logic results in meaningful values.

Comment: For instance, how the value of "A" gets incremented for all cases, which mean that A will always be the greatest number.